# The parameter "logit_bias" is not working properly in openAI

Tags: chatgpt-api, chat-gpt-4

I am trying to use logit_bias to avoid the word "egg" and the tokens for this word are already given in chatGPT [doc](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them) and the code I  used is given below

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = "TokenID"

response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt="The ingrediants of banana bread are",
  temperature=1,
  max_tokens=256,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  logit_bias={"5935" : -100, "9653" : -100 , "1130" : -100, "33856" : -100},
)
print(response)
```

After giving "logit_bias" parameter also the word egg is still appearing in the result
Please tell me what did I missed
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the correct tokenization.  That article appears to be using the tokenizer for GPT3, which is obsolete.  Instead, use the current up-to-date tokenizer for GPT3.5/GPT4: https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer?view=bpe